# make 3 images that are inside three columns appear in the same height level

Tags: html, css

I'm having a hard time figure out how to make the 3 images appear in the same height level. I was trying to use `vertical-align: bottom;` and `margin-bottom` in the paragraph before, but didn't worked.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ueoxc4k/2/embedded/result/

**HTML:**

```
<section class="info">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info__title">
      <h2> Some main title </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="info__widgets">
      <div class="widget">
        <span class="widget__title"> TITLE1 </span>
        <p>
          NORMAL TEXT ABOUT SOMETHING HEHEHE.
        </p>
          <img src="http://avatarmaker.net/free-avatars/avatars/games_225/super_mario_259/super_mario_panic_avatar_100x100_25831.gif"/>
      </div>
      <div class="widget">
        <span class="widget__title"> TITLE 2 </span>
        <p>
          BIGGER TEXT BUT STILL NORMAL BLA BLA HEHE LOREM IPSUM
        </p>
        <img src="http://avatarmaker.net/free-avatars/avatars/games_225/super_mario_259/super_mario_panic_avatar_100x100_25831.gif"/>
      </div>
      <div class="widget">
        <span class="widget__title"> TITLE 3 </span>
        <p>
          SOME BIG TEXT SOME BIG TEXT SOME BIG TEXT SOME BIG TEXT SOME BIG TEXT SOME BIG TEXT SOME BIG TEXT SOME BIG TEXT SOME BIG TEXT SOME BIG TEXT SOME BIG TEXT SOME BIG TEXT 
        </p>
        <img src="http://avatarmaker.net/free-avatars/avatars/games_225/super_mario_259/super_mario_panic_avatar_100x100_25831.gif"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.info {
  position: relative;
  background: #fafafa;
}
.info__title {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2.25rem;
  padding-bottom: 2.25rem;
}
.info__title h2 {
  font-family: Oswald, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #999;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.info__widgets {
  margin-top: 2.25rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.widget {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 2.25rem;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .widget {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1360px) {
  .widget {
    width: 15%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
.widget * {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.widget i:before {
  font-size: 1.875rem;
  color: #ccc;
}
.widget .i-alcohol-shop {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.35);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.35);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.35);
  -o-transform: scale(1.35);
  transform: scale(1.35);
}
.widget__number {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  font-family: Oswald, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.125rem;
  color: #E97228;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
}
.widget__title {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-family: Oswald, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving putting this css on all images:

```
height: 50px;
margin-top: 100px;
```

It's a bit of a crude solution but if you play with these values i think you'll be able to get what you want.